# Chamando a partir do 2 post no loop wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loop, wordpress-theme

estou fazendo um loop no wordpress utilizando o WP_query e preciso que me liste somente a partir do 2 post, ignore o 1 primeiro post.

Antigamente usava o query_posts('offset') para fazer isso, mais utilizando o wp_query não estou conseguindo.

Alguém poderia me da esse help para ver se estou fazendo correto?

segue o código:

```
$args2 = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => '5', // listando 5 posts por página
'offset' => '-1', // mostrando a partir do 2 post.
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'postagem_destacada',
        'value' => '1',
        'compare' => '=='
    )
)); $query_slider2 = new WP_Query($args2);
```

ajuda alguém?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione ao seu array a key "post__not_in" e especifique o ID da primeira postagem.

Você pode fazer como nesse exemplo:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'postagem_destacada',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=='
        ),
    ),
    'showposts' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'asc',
);

$WP_Query = new WP_Query($query);
$WP_Query->the_post();
$ID = $post->ID;

$query['post__not_in'] = array($ID);
$query['posts_per_page'] = 5;
$query['showposts'] = '-1';
$query['order'] = 'desc';

$query_slider2 = new WP_Query($query);
```

Comment: não funcionou tentei fazer da maneira que você colocou mais não funcionou!

Comment: Código atualizado, não tive com testar antes, tente novamente.

Comment: funcionou sim, mais estou agora com outro problema, só quero que liste apenas 2 posts, o 2 e o 3 do loop! http://i.imgur.com/iaXBAmz.jpg olha como fica!

Comment: Certo, se a minha resposta resolveu o seu problema inicial, aconselho que marque esta resposta como aceita e abra um novo tópico para o seu outro problema, assim tornamos mais fácil para outras pessoas que tem o mesmo problema que o seu encontrarem uma solução.